# problem with access controle for modules in yii2

Tags: yii2

i have two type of user in my project.
1.user
2.admin
i defined module for each one of them.
module name for user = users/default/login
module name for admin = adclash/default/login

when i login with adclash/default/login i should have access only to all adclash controllers but also i have access to all controllers in another module(users) to.(if i login with adclash when i shouldnt have access to users module)
whats wrong?

define my users in web.php :

```
    'user'=>[
        'class'=>'yii\web\User',
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        'authTimeout' => 60*60,
        'loginUrl' => ['users/default/login'],
        'identityCookie' => [
            'name' => '_panelUser',
        ]
    ],
    'admin'=>[
        'class'=>'yii\web\User',
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\Admin',
        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        'authTimeout' => 60*30,
        'loginUrl' => ['adclash/default/login'],
        'identityCookie' => [
            'name' => '_panelAdmin',
        ]
    ],
```

and this my defaultControllers source:
adclah module:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'user'=>'admin', // this user object defined in web.php
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login', 'error'],
                    'allow' => true,
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],

            ],

        ],
    ];
}
```

users module:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'user'=>'user', // this user object defined in web.php
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['login', 'error','signup'],
                    'allow' => true,
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],

            ],

        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: didn't know this was possible like this. Do you have some tutorial/docs of how to use it?

Comment: i dont have tutorial.someone teach me this way.if you have tutorial please let me know